# Customizing the look of datepicker

Tags: android, android-datepicker

Is there a way to customize the look of DatePicker in Android?
I should be able to navigate between years and the month
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could make two seperate `NumberPicker` views

```
NumberPicker yearPicker = (NumberPicker)findViewById(R.id.year_picker);
NumberPicker monthPicker = (NumberPicker)findViewById(R.id.month_picker);

yearPicker.setMinValue(2000);
yearPicker.setMaxValue(2015);

monthPicker.setMinValue(1);
monthPicker.setMaxValue(12);
```